# General method to output d{d1,d2,d3...dn} in AnyDice

Tags: anydice

I'm trying to find a more general method to create certain one-sided distributions using anydice.com, such that the values less than or equal to 0 show as 0, and the rest show normally, of a 2dy-8 dice roll.

As an example, for a 2d6-8, I will enter the following:

```
output (2d6-8>0)*d{d1,d2,d3,d4},
```

while for 2d7-8, I will enter the following:

```
output (2d7-8>0)*d{d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6}.
```

These give me exactly what I want, but for higher values of y (2d12, for instance), this becomes more and more cumbersome, so I'm wondering if there is a more general (compact) way to write this out. Also, I do not want to have to make a custom function, but rather use only the single-line general "output xxx" language anydice employs.

Any help or suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi Russ, welcome to rpg.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You want to use the `highest of NUMBER and NUMBER` function in AnyDice instead, so that you don't need to manually specify the outcome based on your prior knowledge of how that roll should behave.

```
output [highest of 2d6-8 and 0]
output [highest of 2d7-8 and 0]
output [highest of 2d12-8 and 0]
```

Each of these will treat all negative results of the `2dX-Y` roll as being equal to 0 instead.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if AnyDice didn't happen to already have a suitable function built in (as noted in [Xirema's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/156805)), the answer *would* be to make a custom function.  [Like this, for example](https://anydice.com/program/17d2c):

```
function: ROLL:n but not less than zero {
  if ROLL < 0 {
    result: 0
  } else {
    result: ROLL
  }
}

output [2d12 - 8 but not less than zero]
```

The reason why you need a (custom or built-in) function is that [if you try to use a die roll in an `if` statement](https://anydice.com/program/17d2d) *outside* of a function, AnyDice will refuse to do run the code and print an error message instead:

> #### calculation error
>
> Boolean values can only be numbers, but you provided "d{?}".
>   Depending on what you want, you might need to create a function.

However, if you pass that same die roll to a function that *expects a number* (i.e. has `:n` after the parameter name), then AnyDice will automatically call the function for *every possible value of the roll* and collect the results back into a custom die.  Inside the function, the parameter (e.g. `ROLL` above) will be a fixed number, and thus expressions involving it (like `ROLL < 0`) will have a definite fixed value that can be safely used in an `if` statement.

(If you want to look at the individual dice in a rolled pool of two or more, you can also make the function expect a sequence by replacing the `:n` with `:s`.  In this particular case it wouldn't make any difference, however, since applying math operations like `- 8` to a dice pool in AnyDice will automatically add up all the dice together before doing the math.  So there's no way to get the individual `d12`s back out of `2d12 - 8`.)